# Ionic Cordova - How to add <permission> tag in Android Manifest.xml

Tags: android, ionic-framework, permissions, android-manifest

I can add **uses-permission** using the code as such -

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/uses-permission" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</edit-config>
```

I use the same code structure below to add **permission**, however I got error **"Unable to graft xml at selector "/manifest/permission"** when add android platform

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/permission" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <permission android:name="test.mobile" />
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use config-file instead to add permission tag in Android Manifest.xml

```
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <permission android:name="test.mobile" />
</config-file>
```